# trap in exported function silently ignored

Tags: bash, bash-trap, bash-function

This Bash script behaves as expected.

**test_this.sh**

```
function run_this() {
    trap "echo TRAPPED" EXIT
    false
    echo $?
}
run_this
```

It prints

```
1
TRAPPED
```

However, when I try to export this function, it fails to trap.

**test_this2.sh**

```
function run_this() {
    trap "echo TRAPPED" EXIT
    false
    echo $?
}
export -f run_this
```

Source this at the command line and run it:

```
> source test_this2.sh
> run_this
```

Results in

```
1
```

Where did the trap go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trap` is ignored when you `export` the function because when you `exit` from your `login` shell (where the function is exported to), there is no longer a `shell` to print `trapped` in. (i.e. there is never an `exit` otherwise you would no longer have a shell.) When you `source test_this2.sh`, you execute it in your `login shell`. When the function completes, it returns to your `login shell` -- **there is no exit.** When you run `test_this.sh`, it executes in a `subshell`, when the `subshell` exits, you get `trapped` printed. If you really want to see what happens when you `exit` your `login shell`, try typing `exit` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'trap' leaving the function use the RETURN signal.
Use the ERR signal to 'trap' errors like your 'false' call.

**test_this.sh**

```
function run_this() {
    trap "echo LEAVING" RETURN
    trap "echo ERROR" ERR
    false
    echo $?
}
export -f run_this
```

Load and export the function

```
source this_this.sh
```

test it

```
run_this
```

returns

```
ERROR
1
LEAVING
```

start subshell

```
bash
```

test again

```
run_this
```

returns

```
ERROR
1
LEAVING
```

So the export works fine.

PS: I'm using bash 4.3.42